# Android browser logs out of ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, session, logout, android-browser

I have a ASP.NET Webforms application that is being used with Motorola Tablets (Android 3.2)
Wenn users navigate it often logs out.

In my logfile i cant find anything unusual, im using a FormsAuthenticationTicket to log the user in.

Any idea how to solve or troubleshout this issue?

Comment: Maybe the authentication cookie expires? Or if you are using Session in addition, the session cookie expires? What timeout values did you configure? Have you enabled sliding expiration?

Comment: Maybe cookie's are the right direction. It only happens on Android, the normal expiration duration is 60 min, on other devices i don't have this issue. Kinda hard to troubleshout on a tablet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the datetime settings, i switched the date time setting to auto and the the timezone to manuel.

It seems to be ok now.